# SPContext in Event Receiver (PortalSiteMapProvider)

Tags: sharepoint, portalsitemapprovider, spcontext

I'm trying to write an event receiver which uses the PortalSiteMapProvider. Without having HTTPContext or SPContext *INSIDE* the event receiver, how would one go about accessing the PortalSiteMapProvider?

Comment: I would be more interested in how you would use an event receiver without having a SPContext object. Please explain.

Comment: You do not have SPContext inside an Event Receiver.

Comment: Which type of event are you using?

Comment: You can determine both the web and list from SPItemEventProperties

Comment: But you don't have SPContext to use the PortalSiteMapProvider. Getting a reference to web/list don't give me context.

Comment: I assume you want to use PortalSiteMapProvider because you want a quick way to query against the web from inside of your event.  Is my assumption true?  What is it you need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your event receiver:

```
var web = properties.Web;    

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, web.Url, string.Empty);

HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StreamWriter(new System.IO.MemoryStream()));

HttpContext impersonatedContext = new HttpContext(request, response);

impersonatedContext.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = web;

HttpContext.Current = impersonatedContext;

SPContext context = SPContext.GetContext(impersonatedContext);
```

You should be able to get your SPContext from that.